# Share internet connection with LAN TV (one step further to use it with Android device)

Tags: laptop, internet, android, tv, internet-sharing

I have bought a LED TV with LAN port.
I successfully shared the wireless internet connection from my laptop to the TV with a LAN cable and now the TV is free to browse internet sites and play anything from the OUTSIDE internet.

For reference I'm giving out my settings to anyone interested in getting here from scratch:

- wireless router ip 192.168.1.1
- cross LAN cable
- laptop configuration:

  - Windows 7 home premium with wireless and lan port

    1) Control panel\Internet connection and sharing (in my Italian version is "Centro connessioni di rete e condivisione)

    2) Change card settings ("Modifica impostazioni scheda")

    3) Right click on Wireless connection\Properties\Sharing tab

    4) Select "Let other users in network to connect through the Internet connection of this computer" ("Consenti ad altri utenti in rete di collegarsi tramite la connessione Internet di questo computer) and select the LAN connection in the drop down list

    5) Click OK and close this window

    6) Right click on Local area network connection ("Connessione alla rete locale (LAN)")\Properties

    7) Select "Internet protocol version 4 (TCP/IPv4)" then click on "Properties"

    8) Select "Use following IP address" radio button and put these values in the right fields:

    - ip 192.168.1.155
    - subnet mask 255.255.255.0
    - dns server 192.168.1.1

    9) Click OK and close this window
- TV configuration:

  - ip 192.168.1.156
  - subnet mask 255.255.255.0
  - gateway 192.168.1.155
  - dns 1 192.168.1.155
  - dns 2 192.168.1.1

With these configurations I'm able to use Smart TV functions such as youtube, facebook, vimeo, etc.

What I'm trying to do now is to use an Android application that enhances the remote functions, such as typing text with a keyboard or read channel guides and permits to view tablet contents such as photos and videos directly on the TV via internet connection.

From my android tablet I downloaded the app (Philips MyRemote by the way) but the app can't see the TV.

From my laptop connected directly to the tv through the LAN cable I'm able to ping the address 192.168.1.156 (the TV's ip) but I am not able to ping it from the tablet, even though it's in the same subnet.

What I would like to ask is if someone can point me to the right direction to make the TV pingable and so visible to the network devices.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What are your tablet's network settings? Can it ping your laptop?

Comment: I'm trying to ping my machine from about an hour.I followed this guide: http://mikemstech.blogspot.it/2011/10/how-to-enable-ping-response-on-windows.html, I created the rule in my firewall but nothing gained, it alwasy says "Request timed out".Only with a Teamviewer connection on from another pc I can ping my laptop (from that specific pc),but that's strange.I only have AVG antivirus as security sw (without firewall) and it's disabled... Any suggestion? Is there a way to check what is blocking ICMP messages?

Comment: It could be your wireless router. I have the firewall in my (wired) one custom configured to not allow outbound ICMP service for security reasons.

Comment: It is already disabled. I always keep it disabled because it's not configurable, I prefer using any software against it.